# How can I pass json value as csv file content in jmeter

Tags: arrays, json, csv, jmeter, json.net

I have try the steps with the help of chatgpt [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoLGc.png). but it's not working in my jmeter5.5.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MZe8.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CXF2.png)
Please guide me thanks

I have try to this api in multiple users (600)
this error is displaying
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcTQX.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the system under test doesn't like `j` character because it expectes a [JSON Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) or a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp)

So I think you need to remove this `jaction=` bit from your CSV file.

In general if you can successfully execute the request using your browser (or other application) you should be able to record the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) and see how the recorded request looks like.

Once done you can replace the recorded hard-coded JSON payload with the value from the CSV file (make sure that it is placed in one line fully and there are no line breaks) to wit your file should look like:

```
{"your-json":"payload #1"}
{"your-json":"payload #2"}
etc.
```

Also if the number of lines in your CSV file is not too big you can consider switching to [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function